# Continuous/Infinite scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have looked for a plugin/script that continues to scroll a website from the start when the bottom is reached, like a continuous loop.

Examples: http://unfold.no/ and http://www.aquiesdonde.com.ar/

I have tried reversed engineering but have not gotten to a conclusion. 
Can anyone **lead me in the right direction what to look for** to find a plugin like this?

I only tend to find scripts that are continuously expanding the page/adding content on scroll-down.

Comment: [Infinite Scrolling using jQuery](http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/#.UHK_LU1vmjA)

Comment: Cheers, but as in the examples I posted, I want to go back to the top when I reach the bottom. Not load new content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a if statement that tells the document if at x amount of pixels go to top y.

The code from: http://www.aquiesdonde.com.ar/

```
/*Scroll*/
var mov = 0;
function handle(delta) {
/*Scroll Action*/
    if (delta < 0){
        if(mov==-10500){
            mov=0;
            moverDown();
        }else{
            moverDown();
        }
    }else{
        if(mov==0){
            mov=-10440;
            moverUp();
        }else{
            moverUp();
        }
    }
};
```

Plus the moverUp/moverDown functions which make the scrolling seamless:

```
/*Scroll Top*/
function moverUp(){
    $('.layout').css( "top", mov+=30 );
};

/*Scroll Down*/
function moverDown(){
    $('.layout').css( "top", mov-=30 );
};

/*Function Scroll*/
function wheel(event){
    var delta = 0;
    if (!event) event = window.event;
    if (event.wheelDelta) {
        delta = event.wheelDelta/120; 
        if (window.opera) delta = -delta;
    } else if (event.detail) {
        delta = -event.detail/3;
    }
    if (delta)
        handle(delta);
        if (event.preventDefault)
                event.preventDefault();
        event.returnValue = false;
};
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this script: https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll

This is what you want to achieve written in JS using JQuery framework.

Comment: Not quiet what I'm after - I want to return to the top of the page/loop the page when I reach the bottom.. See http://unfold.no/ - it's a really nice feature.